# How to Connect to signalR server and register my client method to my signalR server in callback of an AJax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, signalr

This is my working code:

```js
$(function() {
  $.connection.hub.url = 'sampleUrl';
  $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
    var uid = settingInvoiceUID;
    if (uid !== '')
      $.connection.notifyHub.server.registerInHub(uid);
  });

  $.connection.notifyHub;
  $.connection.notifyHub.client.updateClient = function(gInfo) {
    alret('blah blah blah');
  }
});
```

I want to use it as this way and everything will work just server could not call  this method `updateClient` in this code:

```js
$("[id*='qrCodeImage']").click(function() {
  var postUrl = '/sample.aspx/SetAsScanned';
  var postedData = "{data: '" + settingInvoiceUID + "'}";
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: postUrl,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: postedData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data) {
      var result = JSON.parse(data.d);

      if (result.IsSuccess) {
        $.connection.hub.url = 'sampleUrl';
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
          var uid = settingInvoiceUID;
          if (uid !== '')
            $.connection.notifyHub.server.registerInHub(uid);
        });

        $.connection.notifyHub;
        $.connection.notifyHub.client.updateClient = function(gInfo) {
          alret(gInfo);
        }
      });
  });
```

Is it possible to set all of SignalR codes including connection and hub registration and clientMethod in a callBack?

Comment: Are you sure the code is working? I can see an issue in both samples - `alret()`

Comment: Also, the SignalR logic is identical in both instances, so if the latter 'isn't working' then it's not a SignalR problem, but an AJAX one. Have you debugged to ensure the AJAX request is returning a successful response?

Comment: the alert is a sample code... the first code is working correctly

Comment: in second one i have this problem : 
from my server i call $.connection.notifyHub.client.updateClient method , but in js it will NOT invoke

Comment: You need to register at least 1 event handler before calling the start method.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#how-to-establish-a-connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $.getScript(settingSignalRServerPath + "/hubs", function () {
    $.connection.hub.url = settingSignalRServerPath;
    // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
    simpleHubProxy = $.connection.notifyHub;
    //Register to the "updateClient" callback method of the hub
    //This method is invoked by the hub
    simpleHubProxy.client.updateClient = function (gInfo) {
        checkTransactionAndRedirectToMerchant(gInfo);
    }
    $.connection.hub.start()
        .done(function () {
            var uid = '12345';
            $.connection.notifyHub.server.registerInHub(uid);
        })
        .fail(function () {
            console.log('creating conn failed')
        });
});
```

at last i did it  . u can copy this whole code to a method which is invoking in a callBack :D